# Bulk change primary SMTP in AD

Tags: powershell, active-directory

I need switch the primary SMTP address in AD in bulk from users of an certain OU.

smtp:first.last@domain1.com
smtp:flast@domain1.com
SMTP:first.last@domain2.net
smtp:flast@domain2.net

So far I found this but i don't see changes;

```
Get-ADUser -Filter * -SearchBase 'OU=users_test,OU=Test,DC=test,DC=local' -Properties name, mail, ProxyAddresses |
ForEach-Object {  
    # flag to avoid further processing after first match
    $userDone = $false
    
    $proxies = $_.ProxyAddresses | 
        ForEach-Object {
            $proxyAddress = $_ -replace '^SMTP', 'smtp'
            if (!$userDone -and $proxyAddress -like '*@domain1.com') {
                $proxyAddress -replace '^smtp', 'SMTP'
                
                $userDone = $true
            } else {
                $proxyAddress
            }
        }
        $_.ProxyAddresses = $proxies
        #Set-ADUser -instance $_
        Write-Host $proxies
    }
```

Comment: The `Set-ADUser` line is commented out. Is that the way you ran it?

Comment: yes, how it should be?

Comment: The `#` makes it a comment, which means that line is not run. If you want to run `Set-ADUser` (which you need to apply the changes), you need to remove the `#`.

Comment: WARNING: Unable to set new primary address for user@domain.com | !
x500:/o=ExchangeLabs/ou=Exchange Administrative Group (FYDIBOHF23SPDLT)/cn=Recipients/cn=1a7f36303f7e442f8787bf679e8fe26d-userFirstName userLastName

Comment: Move `Write-Host $proxies` above the `Set-ADUser` line and make sure it looks right.

Comment: @GabrielLuci how to exclude list of users?